# обобщенный метод

Tags: java, generics

Всем привет! Прохожу дженерики и не могу их понять.
1) как определить где их использовать? класс, метод, интерфейс?
2) что значит ограничение типов и extends? Что должно быть написано в классе, которым ограничивают?

мне нужно написать метод сравнения любых чисел, ограниченный классом numbers. Метод должен возвращать положительное число - если первое число больше второго, 0 - если числа равны, отрицательное число - если первое число меньше второго.

Написала немного, т.к. не до конца понимаю, что и где использовать

```
public class Numbers {
}
```

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo();
}
```

```
public class Comparator<T>{
    private T obj;
    private T obj2;

    public Comparator(T obj, T obj2) {
        this.obj = obj;
        this.obj2 = obj2;
    }

    public <T> int compareTo(T obj, T obj2) {

    }
}
```

Буду благодарна за объяснения.

Comment: Сейчас в компаратор можно передать любой ссылочный тип данных, нужно ограничить потомками класса Numbers. В методе compareTo() пишите логику сравнения переменных obj и obj2, и всё будет готово. Можно Шилдта открыть, там есть отдельная глава по дженерикам, где все достаточно понятно написано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вы намудрили. Класс `Number` уже существует, им нужно ограничивать тип. Класс `Comparator` тоже переписывать не надо. В общем, всю теорию тут сложно изложить, читайте Шилдта. Ну а по задаче, думаю, вам нужно что-то типа этого:

```
static public <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> int compare(T o1, T o2) {
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

Все `Number` имплементят `Comparable`, поэтому можем прямо у них и вызывать `compareTo()`.
Вызов:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(compare(2, 3));       // -1
    System.out.println(compare(2.3, 3.2));   // -1
    System.out.println(compare(2.3f, 3.2f)); // -1
    System.out.println(compare(3, 2));       // 0
    System.out.println(compare(3.2, 2.3));   // 0
    System.out.println(compare(3.2f, 2.3f)); // 0
    System.out.println(compare(3, 3));       // 1
    System.out.println(compare(2.3, 2.3));   // 1
    System.out.println(compare(2.3f, 2.3f)); // 1
}
```